# Minimum between two boolean decision variables in Pyomo

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, pyomo

I need to do something like this:

```
d1 == min(d2,d3)
```

where d is a decision variable. I need to use Pyomo. In cplex the solution is achieved by the funnction minl, how can do this in Pyomo or in an equivalent linear form?
I searched for a solution on Google and found that I could assert that d1 must be less or equal to d2 and d3. But this do not fit my proble, because if d2 and d3 is equal to 1, d1 <= 1 while I need d1 == 1.

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the *d* variables are binary variables,

```
d1 = min(d2,d3)
```

is really the same as multiplication

```
d1 = d2*d3
```

This is often linearized as

```
d1 <= d2
d1 <= d3
d1 >= d2+d3-1
```

Comment: Thank a lot, this formulation fixed my problem.